# Why do my widgets only show up in one case?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm making a game based off of the periodic table with tkinter. I made the particle frame just fine, so I decided to copy the code and reuse it for the element frame, changing only the variable names. But for some reason, even though the particle frame works just fine, nothing shows up for the element frame. Here is my full code:

```
# Boilerplate

import random
import periodictable as pt
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Periodic Table Game')
root.geometry('350x250')
LightBlue = "#b3c7d6"
Menu = Frame(root)
elementFrame = Frame(root)
particleFrame = Frame(root)
settingsFrame = Frame(root)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for AllFrames in (Menu, elementFrame, particleFrame, settingsFrame):
    AllFrames.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    AllFrames.configure(bg=LightBlue)
def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
show_frame(Menu)

# Menu Frame

Menu.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

MenuTitle = Label(Menu, text="Periodic Table Game", font=("Arial", 15), bg=LightBlue)
MenuTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=25)
MenuTitle.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
MenuTitle.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

MenuButton1 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Guess The Particles", command=lambda: show_frame(particleFrame))
MenuButton1.grid(row=1, column=0)

MenuButton2 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Guess The Element Name", command=lambda: show_frame(elementFrame))
MenuButton2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)

SettingsButton = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Settings", command=lambda: show_frame(settingsFrame))
SettingsButton.grid(row=3, column=0)

# Particle Frame

particleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

BackButtonF2 = Button(particleFrame, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu))
BackButtonF2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

ParticleLabel = Label(particleFrame, text='testing', bg=LightBlue)
ParticleLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=15)

ParticleEntry = Entry(particleFrame)
ParticleEntry.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

ParticleEnter = Button(particleFrame, text='Enter', width=10)
ParticleEnter.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10)

# Element Frame

elementFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

BackButtonF3 = Button(particleFrame, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu))
BackButtonF3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

ElementLabel = Label(particleFrame, text='testing', bg=LightBlue)
ElementLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=15)

ElementEntry = Entry(particleFrame)
ElementEntry.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

ElementEnter = Button(particleFrame, text='Enter', width=10)
ElementEnter.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Why does identical code work only with one frame?

Comment: So why does it work for particleFrame but not elementFrame?

Comment: Sorry. I comment out `import periodictable as pt`. So I can see it. You used `particleFrame` for all widgets, but not  `elementFrame` and `settingframe`. That why you cannot see all two frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisely, because you copied the code you don't spot where the issue is.
When you are defining the element frame widgets you are placing them all into  particleFrame.
Example:

```
BackButtonF3 = Button(particleFrame, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu))
```

should be

```
BackButtonF3 = Button(elementFrame, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu))
```

Comment: Yes, the original code for particleFrame is ok, yes. But it is precisely because you copied it, that you forgot to change the particleFrame variables in all fields for elementFrame, as 3 of us have already commented.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem will be solved.

Change this `particleFrame`, to `elementFrame`

snippet code:

```
BackButtonF3 = Button(elementFrame, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu))
BackButtonF3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

ElementLabel = Label(elementFrame, text='testing', bg=LightBlue)
ElementLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=15)

ElementEntry = Entry(elementFrame)
ElementEntry.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

ElementEnter = Button(elementFrame, text='Enter', width=10)
ElementEnter.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10)
```

Screenshot before:

[image]

Screenshot  after same as `elementFrame` and `particleFrame`:

[image]